# How to create custom variables in wordpress

Tags: shortcode

I made a wordpress faucet site using some plugins, and I would like to make it a little better.

I would like to make a referral link, so when it is `http://free-liteco.in/?r=Your-Address`, I would like that the part `Your-Address` changes from user to user, so it would put the users litecoin address from the profile in the referral link, instead of saying your address.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [get_user_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_meta/) function.

Assuming the litecoin address in the user's profile is stored as user meta, with the key of `litecoin_address` you can output the link like so:-

```php
$litecoin_address = get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'litecoin_address', true );

if( !empty( $litecoin_address ) ){
    // maybe do some additional sanitation of the litecoin address here
    $link = sprintf( 'http://free-liteco.in/?r=%s', $litecoin_address );
    echo $link;
} else {
    echo 'Please login and complete the litecoin address in your profile';
}
```